# How plot the following transformation in the complex plane?

Tags: complex-numbers

I need transform the semiline $x=1,y \geq 1$ on the transform $w(x,y)=\frac{1}{x+yi}$.

Operating, i have $w=\frac{1}{1+y^2}-\frac{yi}{1+y^2}$

But, how i can plot $w$?

Answer (score 1):

**Maple**

```
restart:
with(plots):
w:=(y)->1/(1+y^2)-I*y/(1+y^2);
complexplot(w(y), y =1.. 10);
```

**Mathematica**

```
w[y_] := 1/(1 + y^2) - I*y/(1 + y^2);
ParametricPlot[{Re[w[y]], Im[w[y]]}, {y, 1, 10}]
```